# reference type variable initialisation and storage

Tags: c++

Is this legal?

```
int& foo = 0x00000000;
```

I don't know if 'int' is the right data type. If you wanted to store an address what data type would you use? Or do you have to use a pointer?

in addition to this, is this legal?

```
int foo = 5;
int bar = &foo;
```

Essentially what I'm asking is, is there a way of storing addresses without the use of pointers?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I've been thinking about it too much and I just really want to understand the inner workings.

Comment: @SirYakalot: C++ standard says if reference ever becomes NULL, the compiler/computer may do anything it feels like.  Usually there's a crash involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you wanted to store an address what data type would you use? Or do you have to use a pointer?

For storing addresses, you normally use pointers. If for who-knows-what reasons you to store pointers in an integral type, you can, provided the integral type is big enough to hold the pointer (64bit integer for 64bit pointer etc.).

C++03 AFAIK still doesn't have (or guarantee) integral types large enough to hold pointers, but C99 introduced `intptr_t` typedef which servers just for this purpose. C++11 has it, too (`std::intptr_t` in header `<cstdint>`).

You use it like this:

```
int x;
intptr_t i=(intptr_t)&x;
```

or better

```
intptr_t i=reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&x);
```

note that the value in `i` is implementation defined.

Comment: the `reinterpret_cast` is definitely not necessary. Addresses can be converted into integer types and back. `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to compare equal to the original pointer in C)

Comment: @rubenvb: Pointers and integers **cannot** be converted *implicitly* between in each other. Definitely not in C++ (cf. paragraph 4.10 in C++03 standard), not even in C99 (cf. par. 6.5.16.1 in C99 standard). `reinterpret_cast` is necessary, because the other casts wouldn't do in this case.

Comment: @rubenvb Addresses can be converted to an integral type large enough to hold them, but not explicitly.  You need a `reinterpret_cast`, or some other type of cast which resolves to `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: jpalecek: Then what does C99's 7.18.1.4 imply in this context? C doesn't hace a `reinterpret_cast`, only a `static_cast`-like cast? And I don't see what C++03 4.10 has to do with pointer to integer conversions. (1 talks about nullptr, 2 is pointer to T to pointer to void conversion, and 3 is pointer to T to pointer to S, with S base of T)

Comment: @rubenvb: Cast in C as well as C-style cast in C++ contain functionality of C++'s `reinterpret_cast`. 7.18.1.4 doesn't imply anything about implicit conversions. 4.10 is an exhaustive list of implicit conversions involving pointers; for pointer-to-integer conversions, see 5.2.10/4 (talks about `reintepret_cast`).

Comment: jpalecek: OK didn't know that a C-style cast has `reinterpret_cast`-like functionality hidden underneath. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @rubenvb, yea, that's the "dangerous" part.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this legal?
>   int& foo = 0x00000000;

No.

> is this legal? 
>   int foo = 5;
>   int bar = &foo;

No. In order to convert a pointer to an integer a cast is needed: `reinterpret_cast< int >( &foo )`. You probably want `int* bar = &foo;` instead.

> is there a way of storing addresses without the use of pointers?

No, pointers are the elements used to store addresses. You could cast them to an integer long enough, and then you would be able to 'store' addresses disguised as numbers.

References are not addresses, in fact references aren't anything. They are just a new name for an existing object.

Comment: You cannot assign a pointer (an address) to an `int` without an explicit cast (and perhaps not at all).  There is **no** implicit conversion which does this.

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet <strike>is perfectly fine</strike> might compile, but probably doesn't do what you want. The first is nonsensical.

If you want to declare a pointer to an int, it goes `int *foo`.

You can then do:

```
int foo = 5;
int *bar = &foo;
```

With them declared thusly, this is what you can and cannot do:

```
*bar = 6; // foo is now 6.
bar = 6;  // bar now points to the blackness of space
*bar = 6; // Seg fault!
```

Comment: I don't think any sane C++ compiler will accept the 2nd snippet (it cannot implicitly cast from `int*` to `int`).

Comment: It would definitely throw a warning, but I've seen it happen exactly like that.

Comment: Well, in gcc it is an error by default. You can make it a warning by passing the `-fpermissive` flag.

Comment: I wouldn't call the second snippet perfectly fine. It'll (at least wih an additional cast) convert the pointer value to an int, but the int might not be able to store such an address. A typical example is most 64 bit platforms where pointer values are 64 bits, and an int is 32 bit.

Comment: I think I was under the false impression that you could initialise 'reference type' variables. Am I right in now thinking that this is not something you can do?

Comment: Correct. "Reference Type" only exists in function argument lists. Even so, there is some debate as to whether or not you should ever use it (Google Inc is officially against it).

Comment: @Chriszuma: References only exist in function arguments list??? What language that is? `int& bar = foo;` is a perfectly valid local definition and initialization of a local variable.

Comment: @SirYakalot: `int foo = 5;` as in the answer.

Comment: -1: References are types, certainly available outside of function argument list contexts... For example as class data members, to prevent copies and secure yourself vs null pointers (a compiler is stricter for unitialized references). See for more info, C++11 `8.3.2. References`.

Comment: @K-ballo OK, now i'm a little confused though. A variable has two bits - a memory address and a stored value (in the case of a pointer this value is another memory address). So in the case of int& bar = foo. The value of bar is the memory address of foo, but what is the memory address of bar? If it even has one, wouldn't that make it a pointer?

Comment: OK no wait, i'm being stupd aren't I? in the case of int& bar = foo; bar has the same memory address AND the same value. It's not even a copy, it's an alias. Right?

Comment: @SirYakalot: The value of `bar` is the value of `foo`, and it does not have a memory address. In fact if you do `&bar` it will give you a pointer to `foo`, if you do `sizeof(bar)` then you will get the `sizeof(foo)`, and so on... A reference is just a new name or alias for an existing variable. Indeed it is just an alias.

Comment: @K-ballo A reference is **not** a variable, according to the standard.  Both variables and references associate names with objects, but the association works differently.  A variable declaration associates a name with an object in the compiler; a reference associates a name with the object used to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

`int& foo = 0x00000000;` is trying to make a reference to a literal, which won't work because literals are constant. This works though:

```
const int& foo = 0x00000000;
```

This creates a reference to a constant integer 0. Whenever you try to use `foo` in your code, it will be 0.

References are often implemented as pointers by the compiler, but this is an implementation detail that should be invisible to you.

Pointers were invented for storing addresses, the only reason not to use it is to use a smart pointer class instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet,

```
int& foo = 0x00000000;
```

is illegal; you can't initialize a reference with a temporary unless it
is a reference to const.  The following would be legal:

```
int const& foo = 0x00000000;
```

, but I can't think of a reason anyone might want to do it.  It is 
effectively  the same thing as:

```
extern int const foo = 0x00000000;
```

The second snippet,

```
int foo = 5;
int bar = &foo;
```

is also illegal.  The type of `&foo` is `int*`, and there is no implicit
conversion of `int*` to `int`.  You can use an explicit conversion
(`reinterpret_cast`), but only if `int` is large enough to hold all
possible pointer values without loss.  In such cases, it's better to use
`intptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`), which is a typedef to an integral type
large enough to hold all pointer values.  (Formally: `<stdint.h>` was
introduced in C90/C++11, and `intptr_t` isn't guaranteed to be present
if there isn't a large enough integral type.  C90/C++11 require `long
long`, however, and require it to be 64 bits, so this will only be a
problem if you have a machine with an address space of over
2<sup>64</sup>.  Which is not something I'd worry about.)

Comment: Wrong. There's no `ptrint_t` in the standard. Also, it doesn't require `long long` to be at least 64 bits (it does, however, require the implementation to provide some type at least 64 bits wide).

Comment: @jpalecek A rather obvious typo.  It should be `intptr_t`.  And the standard most definitely does require `long long` to be at least 64 bits, albeit indirectly; it requires the definitions in `<climits>` to be the same as in C, and C requires `LLONG_MAX` to be at least 2^63-1.